# Get Values of fields from Indices of Elastic Search that are not used in Aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, group-by, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am using aggregations in Elastic Search. I want a value of field which is not being used in the aggregations. I know there is one to one mapping between the field that is being used in the grouping and the field i require. So, is there a way i can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly then try using [TopHits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html). 
You would add that as a sub-aggregation to your terms aggregation and specify which fields you’d like to be returned (with include parameter). 
Then when your accessing your resulting terms aggregation you can retrieve TopHits aggregation and get the fields you require/want.

More info can be found [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html).